# How to perform a calculation using attributes of groups of features in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcpy, sql

I have a table with information about 2000 aquifers (thickness, area, depth, volume etc.; there are 20 fields approximately). One of these fields is an internal code, i.e. `DK_12_456_XXX`; the last 3 digits of the code tell us to which groundwater body the aquifer belongs to. For each groundwater body there is more than one aquifer, and there are approximately 400 groundwater bodies.

I need to calculate the weighted thickness for each groundwater body using the formula:

[image: Formula]

Area Aquifer and Thickness Aquifer are fields in the table. Notice that the formula only refers to the acquifers belonging to that groundwater body.

I have thought about doing it using "Select by Attribute" and entering an expression that selects from the "internal code" field using only the 3 last digits. That would give me all the aquifers for the groundwater body that I define, and from there I could calculate the groundwater weighted thickness. However that would force me to do it manually and, as I mentioned, there are about 400.

How can I calculate this all at once?

Comment: =right(Column,3) will give you the last 3 digits as a new attribute with the last 3 digits. Then at the start of your model just put the "Select By Attributes" tool. Complex calculations a(such as this) are merely a few simple calculations combined.

Comment: Not sure my title is all that great either, but it more closely describes what you're trying to do. Also, while I realize the equation you posted uses the 'acquifer' spelling, I changed everything else to remove the c per both spell check and most other sources I could find. I'm not sure if the c is actually wrong, archaic, or varies by language.

Comment: Thanks for the title review, I have also changed the formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculating a couple of new fields and using the [Summary Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000) tool should be one method able to get you what you want.

1. Add a new field to hold the area * thickness for each aquifer and
   field calculate that value for all the aquifers.
2. Add a second new field to hold the water body id portion of your
   internal code and populate it as suggested in the comment.
3. Now run the Summary Statistics tool using your new area * thickness
   field and the area field as Statistics fields with a type of Sum,
   and the new water body id field as a Case field. This will generate
   a new table (not tied to the aquifer geometry) that contains one row
   for each water body id with the sum of those two field values and
   another column called Frequency that tells you how many aquifers are
   part of that water body.
4. Add a new field to this new table to hold the weighted thickness,
   and field calculate that by dividing the two summary fields per your
   posted equation.